# $d_1^2\cdot d_2^2=a^2\cdot c^2+b^2\cdot d^2$ iff $A+C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $B+D=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Let $ABCD$ a quadrilateral,  $a,b,c,d$ the lengths of his edges and $d_1,d_2$ the lengths of diagonals. Show that $d_1^2\cdot d_2^2=a^2\cdot c^2+b^2\cdot d^2$ iff $A+C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $B+D=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I tried to prove it with scalar product of vectors but I am stuck.

My idea: 
$d_1^2=\vec{AC}^2=(\vec{AB}+\vec{BC})^2=AB^2+2 \vec{AB}\cdot \vec{BC} +{BC}^2$.

$d_2^2=\vec{BD}^2=(\vec{BC}+\vec{CD})^2=BC^2+2 \vec{BC}\cdot \vec{CD} +{CD}^2$.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with this problem. What we should have instead is: $d_1^2 \cdot d_2^2= 2(a^2 \cdot c^2 + b^2 \cdot d^2)$

Comment: Then the proof proceeds by an application of Ptolemy's Theorem.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the sufficiency by algebra, but there is more synthetic treatment, e.g. see [this blog](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1090h1033881s3_359_ptolemys_theorem_and_generalized_ptolemys_relation).